# SimpleTCP doesn't allow me to connect on multiple machines, is it restricted to localhost only?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp, nuget

I am just getting started with TCP servers and I have started an "online card game" project with quite simple tasks actually. The problem is that this works perfectly on localhost but it doesn't seem to work on multiple devices.

I am running the server on a computer that has Visual Studio and the client on an other computer that doesn't run VS (which doesn't prevent it from running the WinForms program btw).

So here is the code for the client:

```
client = new SimpleTcpClient();
client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
try 
{
    client.Connect(TextIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextPort.Text));
    textStatus.Text = "Connected\r\n";
}
catch(Exception)
{
    textStatus.Text = "PORT OR IP UNAVAILABLE";
    ConnectButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

And here is the code for the server:

```
SimpleTcpServer server;

server = new SimpleTcpServer();
server.Delimiter = 0x13;
server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;

if (server.IsStarted == false)
{
    textBox1.Text += "Server starting";
    System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(textBoxIP.Text);
    server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPort.Text));
}
```

Comment: in what way does it not allow you to connnect?

Comment: display the exception you are getting in the client

Comment: Might be the firewall on the server box preventing external connections to the port.

Comment: I have a personnalized exception that returns an error if the port or IP is incorrect, but I am sure they are !

Comment: What IP address did you put in the server's text box?

Comment: I use this method to generate the IP:
`public static string GetIP()
        {
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
            return myIP;
        }`
It should recognize the computer's IP and print it int the txtBox

Comment: If I go on ipconfig (on cmd prompt) which Ip address should be used for the server app?

Comment: The server should always listen to `0.0.0.0`, which means _any_ IP address. If you specify anything else then you are limiting the server to accept connections from only that specific IP address.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [TCP Client program won't connect to my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249100/tcp-client-program-wont-connect-to-my-server)

Comment: @VisualVincent, so what IP should the client choose ?

Comment: The client should connect to the IP of the machine that the server runs at. If it's in your local network you can find it through your router or on the server machine itself through Windows Settings (https://www.avast.com/c-how-to-find-ip-address) or the `ipconfig` command. If the server is on a different network you have to forward the port in the server's router and connect to the server's public IP address (find it by visiting a site like https://www.whatsmyip.org/ on the server machine).